# Python/Pandas: create summary table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

In a python pandas dataframe "df", I have the following columns:

```
user_id | song_id | song_duration | song_title | artist | listen_count
```

Many users might have listened to the same song - therefore the song is not unique in this table. I would like to create a second dataframe with just song information (with unique song_ids).

```
song_id | song_title | artist
```

I manage to create a table with song_id and song_title.

```
song_df = df.groupby('song_id').song_title.first()
```

How can I add, the column "artist" into this?

This doesn't work:

```
song_df = df.groupby('song_id').df['song_title','artist'].first()
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'df'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC try omit `.df`:

```
df.groupby('song_id')['song_title','artist'].first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just drop the duplicates of selected columns

```
song_df = df[['song_id','song_title','artist']].drop_duplicates()
```